# Google Cloud SQL - How to Terminate Import

Tags: mysql, import, google-cloud-sql

I have a 2nd generation instance of Cloud SQL that originally failed on import of a large CSV file (approx 18 million records) -- the first run.

I tweaked the file, re-uploaded and attempted another import -- the second run.

While the first run imported within hours, the second run is still running 2 days later. I am not able to kill the process via mysql 'show processlist; kill ' as the process owner is **cloudsqlimport** so I get an error of :

> **You are not owner of thread 8949**

I am not able to delete the Cloud SQL instance as that presents the error:

> **Operation failed because another operation was already in progress.**

So it appears that I have no way of knowing when and if the import process will terminate nor any way to just delete the Cloud SQL instance to not incur charges for an unusable instance of Cloud SQL.

Likewise, I am not able to delete the database.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated as I seem to have no options for resolving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please email to cloud-sql@google.com with your full instance name and a link to this thread for reference.

Comment: I emailed cloud-sql@google.com and they quickly resolved the problem for me. Here is their explanation: " 

The import csv was stuck because of some networking issue with GCS. I've terminated the import operation. Sorry about the trouble. We've seen cases like this before and are trying to improve it."

Comment: vincenzo@, thanks for the follow up!